# How can the react-virtualized CellMeasurer re-render connected components that have dynamic height?

Tags: redux, react-virtualized

The react-virtualized project enables me to efficiently render a very large list of components. In my project, the list items are container components, i.e., components that are connected to the redux store. They only know their ID, and the container component is responsible for fetching all the relevant data, such as the body text, date, username, etc.

The problem that I face is calculating the height of these components. React-virtualized has a [CellMeasurer component](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md) for calculating dynamic height, but CellMeasurer measures the height for the default state of the component, which is 0 in my container component, since the data has yet to be fetched by the container component when it renders the first time.

Is there a way I can force the recalculation of the component height when the container loads the content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

react-virtualized aggressively caches measurement and position data for performance. It provides an API to reset that data for a specific row or column though. :)

You may find [this demo](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/800ca3e3af39ce970a08ffb48bacf977e5afa7e1/playground/chat.js#L43-L44) useful to glance at. The key parts it highlights is that- if a row (or column) size has potentially changed- you need to first let `CellMeasurer` know to remeasure the row. `resetMeasurements` resets all measurements but if only a single row has changed then it's more performant to use `resetMeasurementForRow(index)` (or, you guessed it, `resetMeasurementForColumn(index)`).

Next you'll need to let `List` (or `Table` or `Grid`) know that the size has changed also- since size impacts position and these components cache position data. If you're using `Table` or `List` then the method you want to use is `recomputeRowHeights(index)`. If you're using `Grid` then it would be `recomputeGridSize ({ columnIndex, rowIndex })`.

Comment: Thanks Brian, you rock!

Comment: Are these methods deprecated? I can't seem to find resetMeasurements anywhere in the codebase.

Comment: Tom, you'll want to use [`CellMeasurerCache`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md#cellmeasurercache) with `CellMeasurer`. The former has methods `clear(row, col)` and `clearAll()`.